# How do i put online database into local database

Tags: android, mysql, kotlin

I have question me and my partner making project and he asked me to connect my database into his local database this is code i know which connects it to recycler view and im kinda new to coding sorry can i have some help?

```
var url = "website"
    var rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    var jar = JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,
            Response.Listener {

                var list = ArrayList<Meal>()
                for (x in 0..it.length()-1)
                    list.add(Meal(it.getJSONObject(x)
                            .getString("Country"),
                            it.getJSONObject(x)
                                    .getString("Infected"),
                            it.getJSONObject(x)
                                    .getString("Recovered"),
                            it.getJSONObject(x)
                                    .getString("Deaths"),
                            it.getJSONObject(x).getInt("id")))



            }, Response.ErrorListener {  })
    rq.add(jar)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) persistence library provides an abstraction layer over SQLite to allow for more robust database access while harnessing the full power of SQLite.

Comment: Would i able to save data into local database with room?

Comment: Yes , and it is so easy to use , and implements sqlite functions .